# opening window and navigating through page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to navigate a webpage with a content script. However the function keeps running because every time the page changes it runs through the script. I was wondering if there was a better way to do this as it is a resource hog and also disallows the user to interact with the page because of the constant refreshing.

Here's the code in question, sorry if it looks weird. I do not have more then a few weeks of knowledge in jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Made it here" + window.location.href);

    loc = window.location.href;
    match = loc.match('http://url.com/uc/');
    if (match) {

        window.location = "http://url.com/uc/health/index/1";
        console.log("2 here");

        window.location = "http://url.com/uc/health/communication/createSelectTemplate";

        console.log("3 here");
        chrome.storage.local.get('formOption', function(result) {
            document.getElementById('formTemplate').value = result.formOption;
            document.forms[0].submit();
         });

    }
});
```

The reason i have to navigate three windows before using values because  whoever made this website has timeout cookies and the pages can not be called before the previous one loads. 
It is a content script tho, so all the code is on the next page. Maybe if there was a way to check exact url? But when i was playing with that awhile back the computer didn't distinguish between.

```
urlhere.com/uc/
```

and

```
urlhere.com/uc/health/index/1
```

Comment: why you have $(document).ready inside of $(document).read ?

Comment: `window.location` will load new page url with new content  and all next code wont work

Comment: I was trying to wait for each page to ready. But looking into it it does nothing so I'm removing them.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: what isn't correct with what i'm doing tho? that is the content script in question. And I am asking if there is a better way, specifically between navigating pages.

Comment: @BrandenHam, At a minimum, I am asking for a *manifest.json*. For a Chrome extension, a Firefox WebExtension, etc. the *manifest.json* file defines how your extension is organized, how scripts are loaded, what permissions you have, etc. Without it a question about such extensions almost never has enough information to be answering the question without some amount of *guessing* as to what is really going on. In order for any debugging question to be on-topic a [mcve], which is sufficient for us to duplicate the problem, is required.

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate all the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem with such questions. Without a [mcve] the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: ohhhh you were looking for manifest. okay I thought i was structuring something wrong

Comment: NOTE: Using `$(document).ready()` in a content script is usually, at best, redundant.  The default time that a content script is loaded, using the `content_scripts` key in the *manifest.json*, is well *after* the `$(document).ready()` function would normally be executed. The only time the content script would be loaded prior to that event firing is if you specified `document_start` for the [`run_at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts#run_at) key.

Comment: You just fixed my lag between pages, thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you navigate (e.g. immediately after assigning `window.location`), your script stops executing is unloaded with the page, and when the next page loads, the content scripts are indeed loaded again. If the **same script** is loaded, with the **same initial state**, it will of course execute the same operation.

Possible solutions (there are many):

1. Be more precise with your matching (= better notice the actually changing state).

   `loc.match('http://url.com/uc/')` will only check that the address *includes* that string - which all URLs you show do. Why not just use `loc == 'http://url.com/uc/'` (and check for intermediate pages)?
2. Use fine-grained content scripts (= load different scripts).

   Manifest defines which pages get what scripts on load. I assume you have something like this:

   ```
   "content_scripts" : [{
     "js" : ["jquery.js", "content1.js"],
     "matches": ["http://*"]
   }]
   ```

   You can make several scripts and let Chrome parse the URLs. For example, `content1.js` will do the first redirect, `content2.js` will do the second.

   ```
   "content_scripts" : [{
     "js" : ["jquery.js", "content1.js"],
     "matches": ["http://url.com/uc/"]
   }, {
     "js" : ["jquery.js", "content2.js"],
     "matches": ["http://url.com/uc/health/index/1"]
   }]
   ```
3. Use some persistent state (that persists between navigation) to indicate which stage of redirect are you on (= control changing state yourself).

   The page's [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is ideal for this, as it's only persistent within the tab:

   ```
   if (match) {
     switch (sessionStorage.redirectStage) {
       case 3:
         // We're at the final page, do actual work
         break;
       case 2:
         sessionStorage.redirectStage = 3;
         window.location = "http://url.com/uc/health/communication/createSelectTemplate";
         break;
       default: // Includes initial state when it's unset
         window.location = "http://url.com/uc/health/index/1";
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: You're a life saver and gave a lot of good info! Thank you so much.

Comment: Tho, do you think your third answer would be a little better for performance compared to the first which is what i have modified?